# when i decript the username and password by using following code i get an error like startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: c#-4.0

```
    public string DecryptValue(string strText)
    {
        string DecriptedValue ="";
        string String = strText.Substring(26); // This line fails
        int Count = String.Length - 5;
        string EncripEdText = String.Substring(0, Count);
        int TotalChar = EncripEdText.Length / 2;
        int J = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= TotalChar; i++)
        {

            string EnChar = EncripEdText.Substring(J, 2);
            string Decrypt = FindPos(EnChar);
            DecriptedValue = DecriptedValue + Decrypt;
            J = J + 2;
        }
        return DecriptedValue;
    }

    public static string FindPos(string EnChar)
    {
        string StringValue = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.*@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        string Value = StringValue.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(EnChar), 1);
        return Value;
    }
```

Comment: Well presumably `strText` doesn't have 26 characters... please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, and explain what you've done to diagnose the error, given the (pretty clear) message...

Comment: I'd also *strongly* advise you not to use `String` as a variable name. (And in general, use camelCase for variable names instead of PascalCase.)

Comment: Building on the other comments, are you attempting to only use up to a maximum of 26 characters of `strText` (to exclude additional characters where it exceeds 26)?

Comment: That exception btw  is mentioned in the [msdn documentation for String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

check for your argument length before taking the substring:

```
 public string DecryptValue(string strText)
    {
        if (strText.Length<26)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("invalid argument length");
          return;
        }
        string DecriptedValue ="";
        string myString = strText.Substring(26); // This line fails
        int myCount = myString.Length - 5;
        ...
}
```